# jonkykong/SideMenu. Can not get Options to work

Tags: swift

The Sidemenu is working - except I can not change any of the options.

I am using the latest SideMenu (6.1.2)

What am I doing wrong?

```
func setupSideMenu() {

    let menu = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeftMenuNavigationController") as! UISideMenuNavigationController

    menu.alwaysAnimate = false
    menu.presentationStyle = .viewSlideOutMenuOut
    menu.completionCurve = .easeInOut
    menu.menuWidth = 600

    present(menu, animated: true, completion: nil)


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I went with this sidemenu because it had so many stars on Git.

fact is that it is very undocumented for non-experts. And the Stackoverflow support is weak.

I was just going with a simple storyboard approach.

Here is what I did for getting the settings to work.

First I had to add the Segue.

Inside the segue I created a makeSettings().

There I could set the things I wanted to add.

Is this the proper way to do things?  I don't know but it works for me. Good luck.

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    guard let sideMenuNavigationController = segue.destination as? UISideMenuNavigationController else { return }
    sideMenuNavigationController.settings =  makeSettings()
}
```

A few simple settings

```
private func makeSettings() -> SideMenuSettings {

    var settings = SideMenuSettings()
    settings.presentationStyle = .menuSlideIn
    settings.menuWidth = min(view.frame.width, view.frame.height) * 0.75
    settings.blurEffectStyle = nil
    settings.presentationStyle.presentingEndAlpha = 0.5

    return settings

}
```